# DDOS and Blocking IP's

Tags: linux, centos, firewall

I'm experiencing issues with the server and noticed that i'm under some sort of a DDOS attack, i have blocked the IP's in the Firewall, yet the IP's show up in netstat.

Is this normal?

```
tcp        0      1 10.1.1.59:80                DDOS.IP.HERE:39159               FIN_WAIT1   
tcp        0      1 10.1.1.59:80                DDOS.IP.HERE:40090          FIN_WAIT1   
tcp        0      1 10.1.1.59:80                DDOS.IP.HERE:40219          FIN_WAIT1   
tcp        0      1 10.1.1.59:80                DDOS.IP.HERE:42108          FIN_WAIT1   
tcp        0      1 10.1.1.59:80                DDOS.IP.HERE:43430          FIN_WAIT1   
tcp        0      1 10.1.1.59:80                DDOS.IP.HERE:44562          FIN_WAIT1   
tcp        0      1 10.1.1.59:80                DDOS.IP.HERE:46282          FIN_WAIT1   
tcp        0      1 10.1.1.59:80                DDOS.IP.HERE:46642          FIN_WAIT1   
tcp        0      1 10.1.1.59:80                DDOS.IP.HERE:49739          FIN_WAIT1   
tcp        0      1 10.1.1.59:80                DDOS.IP.HERE:50050          FIN_WAIT1   
tcp        0      1 10.1.1.59:80                DDOS.IP.HERE:50644          FIN_WAIT1   
tcp        0      1 10.1.1.59:80                DDOS.IP.HERE:51843          FIN_WAIT1   
tcp        0      1 10.1.1.59:80                DDOS.IP.HERE:52098          FIN_WAIT1   
tcp        0      1 10.1.1.59:80                DDOS.IP.HERE:53080          FIN_WAIT1   
tcp        0      1 10.1.1.59:80                DDOS.IP.HERE:54026          FIN_WAIT1
```

Comment: FYI, there are also a lot of "ESTABLISHED" for the same IP.

Answer (score 1):

If your firewall is definitely working, try killing these connections and see if they come back. Restart the daemon they are connected to, reboot or check out this discussion:

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/is-there-a-way-to-drop-connections-415843/